# C++ implementation of XML schema XSD 1.1?

Tags: c++, xml, xsd, xsd-1.1

Is there any existing  C++ implementation of the XML Schema XSD 1.1?

I found xerces-c++-3.1.1, but it only implements XSD 1.0.
The java counterpart of this project does implement XSD 1.1.

I am notably looking for a way to implement  the 'assert' functionality.

Comment: Are you sure?  According to the [xerces website](http://xerces.apache.org/): _Xerces-C++ is faithful to the XML 1.0 **and 1.1** recommendations and many associated standards._

Comment: Yes that is confusing indeed but that is about the xml 1.1 standard not the xsd 1.1 (XML Schema 1.1). On the same page, you will see the wanted feature in the java section.

Comment: I am also looking for a c++ library. Have you found any?

Comment: Is expensive, but try in https://www.saxonica.com/products/feature-matrix-9-9.xml

Comment: Try too https://www.altova.com/manual/RaptorXML/dotnetapiv2/html/html/R_Project_Documentation.htm

Comment: You can vote for XSD 1.1 in Xerces-C++ here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XERCESC-2198

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only released XSD 1.1 processors I am aware of are Xerces-J and Saxon-EE, which are both Java-based (though Saxon-EE is also released on .NET).

**(EDIT, SIX YEARS LATER)**

There is also an implementation from Altova.

Comment: Is it available now for c++ in  xerces-c++-3.2.2 ?

Comment: Not as far as I know (but I wouldn't necessarily know).

Comment: does altova provide c++ libraries to support xsd 1.1

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer to that by asking a new question. Comments on six-year old questions reach a very small audience.